# Android ADB SMS : adb shell service call isms , how to turn Delivery Report Request?

Tags: android, sms, adb

```
adb shell service call isms 7 i32 1 s16 "com.android.mms" s16 "+1234567890" s16 "null" s16 "'text is here'" s16 "null" s16 "null"
```

This code , send sms without problem, but i want to turn "delivery report request on".
But how to do it ?

because when you send sms from command line, it's ignores your phone settings and do not request delivery report on outgoing messages.

Comment: Just checking, but you know delivery in this context just means it was delivered to a remote carrier.  It may not have gone to the other user's phone, much less actually been read.  It doesn't even guarantee it will get to the other user's phone.  Its of pretty limited use.

Comment: So is it possible to use adb and send sms with delivery report request ?